# Sliding without hiding element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-animate

Is there a way to animate new DOM elements without having to hide them first? If so, how?

For example, what I'm doing now is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".link", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var count = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/get_data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { total_count: count  },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".new-elements").append(data).hide().slideDown(function() {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you try to add css (for default for these elements) for example `display: none` or if you prefer `opacity: 0` only, then you try to animate them.